# Creating XML Using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<?php
$xml =new SimpleXMLElement('<OTA_HotelAvailRQ></OTA_HotelAvailRQ>');

$xml->addChild("AvailRequestSegments");
    $AvailRequestSegment = $xml->addChild("AvailRequestSegment");
        $StayDateRange = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("StayDateRange");
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("Duration", "P2N");
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("Start", $Start);
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("End", $End);
        $RoomStayCandidates = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("RoomStayCandidates");
                $RoomStayCandidates->addAttribute("123", "321");

        $HotelSearchCriteria = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("HotelSearchCriteria");

echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

The XML I need to generate is

```
<OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
   <AvailRequestSegments>
      <AvailRequestSegment>
         <StayDateRange Duration="P2N" Start="2018-10-17+03:00" End="2018-10-19+03:00" />
         <RoomStayCandidates>
            <RoomStayCandidate Quantity="1">
               <GuestCounts IsPerRoom="true">
                  <GuestCount Count="2" AgeQualifyingCode="10" />
               </GuestCounts>
            </RoomStayCandidate>
         </RoomStayCandidates>
         <HotelSearchCriteria>
            <Criterion ExactMatch="false">
               <Position />
               <Address FormattedInd="true">
                  <CityName>Athens Center</CityName>
                  <County>'.$Country.'</County>
                  <CountryName Code="GR" />
               </Address>
            </Criterion>
         </HotelSearchCriteria>
      </AvailRequestSegment>
   </AvailRequestSegments>
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
```

But whenever I add a child [RoomStayCandidates ] node to `$AvailRequestSegment` it is been added as child to `$StayDateRange` .

The XML generated for my code is 
[XML Generated for My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdZmB.png)

I think my code is correct. but i don't get the exact output.
Please help in this regards.
TIA

Comment: Can you show us the generated xml ?

Comment: Can't replicate using the code you've posted: https://eval.in/1006454 . `<RoomStayCandidates>` is added under the `<AvailRequestSegment>` element as expected.

Comment: Check the XML enerated for my Code Image plz

Comment: Please could you [edit] to include a [mcve]: a piece of code, the output you want *that piece of code to generate*, and the output (as text, not a link to an image) that *that piece of code actually generates*. The current example of what you need to generate has lots of content that doesn't appear in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xml =new SimpleXMLElement('<OTA_HotelAvailRQ></OTA_HotelAvailRQ>');

$xml->addChild("AvailRequestSegments");
    $AvailRequestSegment = $xml->addChild("AvailRequestSegment");
        $StayDateRange = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("StayDateRange");
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("Duration", "P2N");
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("Start", $Start);
                $StayDateRange->addAttribute("End", $End);
        $RoomStayCandidates = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("RoomStayCandidates");
                $RoomStayCandidates->addAttribute("123", "321");

        $HotelSearchCriteria = $AvailRequestSegment->addChild("HotelSearchCriteria");

echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

This Worked. Thank You.